# How to call a function to search an element an a 2D array?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get my homework done, but there is something is going wrong.

If a 2D array was in the main function, and I want to call a function, which its task is searching for an element in the 2D array, which the user enters the wanted element in the main function. If the wanted element was found, call a function to find its factorial then print the result in the main function, otherwise, call another function to show that the wanted element was not found.

I've tried the lines of code using Visual Studio 2019 as well as Dev C++.

My program does about 13 tasks which I organized them in a Switch Statement,
and the case of doing that task is Case number 9.

But once I enter the element I want to search in the console.
if the element existed in the array, the output always shows up like this:
"
 Number 3 Found at position: 4
 Factorial of 3 is: 6
3
"
whether the user entered 3 or else number.

Even if it was not found, the output is the same.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// declaring a function to search within B1 array.
int search_B1(int[][3], int, int);  

// declaring a function to find the fatorial of the found element.
int fact_num(int);

// declaring a function to print out a searching error.
void search_error();

// This is the main function. Program execution begins and ends here.
int main()
{
     int B1[3][3], i, j;

     cout << " - Please enter the elements of B1 array: \n";
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        cout << "B1[" << i << "]" << "[" << j << "] = ";
        cin >> B1[i][j];
    }
}
...
...
...
    case 9:
{
    int num;
    cout << endl << " Enter the element to search in B1 array: ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl << search_B1(B1, 3, num) << endl;
    break;
}
}

/**********************************************************************/

// This function is called when user inserts '9'
int search_B1(int B1[][3], int num , int)
{
    int i, j, flag = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
        {
            if (num == B1[i][j])
            {
                flag = 1;
                cout << " Number " << num << " Found at position: " << j + 1 << endl;
                fact_num(num);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (flag == 0)
    {
    search_error();
}
return num;
}
/**********************************************************************/

// This function relates to ' search_B1 ' function.
int fact_num(int num)
{
int fact = 1, f;
for (f = 1; f <= num; f++)
{
    fact *= f;
}
cout << " Factorial of " << num << " is: " << fact;
return fact;
}
/**********************************************************************/

// This function relates to ' search_B1 ' function.
void search_error()
{
cout << " The wanted number was not Found in the array!";
}
/**********************************************************************/
```

I expected the output of searching will be like this:
Example:
If the user entered the elements of the array as '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9' and searched about the element '9'

IF THE WANTED ELEMENTS WAS FOUND:
   the output will be :

"Number 9 Found at position: 4
 Factorial of 9 is: 362880"

IF THE WANTED ELEMENTS WAS NOT FOUND:
   the output will be :

"The wanted number was not Found in the array!"

Comment: Welcome to SO. you should be more specific in your question to maximize the chance to have a valuable answer. See [ask]

Comment: `for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)` : Array indexing in C++ starts at `0`, not `1`. You have to change all of the `for` loops you have to `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)` (and respectively for the nested loops with `j`)

Comment: In `case 9` the function call is `search_B1(B1, 3, num);` and the implementation is `int search_B1(int B1[][3], int num , int) { ... cout << " Number " << num << " Found at position: " << j + 1 << endl; ...}`, meaning that it will always receive `3` and it will always print `Number 3 found at...`. The last argument doesn't even have a variable name, so I guess it's a typo and you wanted to pass the array size too.

Comment: Could you show me what the final code should be?

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behaviour filling and searching the array

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) // B[3][j] is never an element
{
    for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++) // B[i][3] is never an element
```

Array indices start from 0. If you want to display indices from 1, do arithmetic in the output

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        std::cout << "B1[" << (i + 1) << "]" << "[" << (j + 1) << "] = ";
        std::cin >> B1[i][j];
    }
}
```